# New React 18 SSR architecture

Tags: reactjs

Following the discussion [here](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/37), if I warp all the lazy components inside one single `Suspense` instead of wrapping each component with their own individual `Suspense`, will I still make use of the new selective/progressive SSR?

Note I'm using Gatsby, so I don't (and properly should not) provide a fallback.

```
const About = lazy(() => import("sections/index/About"));
const Contact = lazy(() => import("sections/index/Contact"));
const Education = lazy(() => import("sections/index/Education"));
const Footer = lazy(() => import("sections/index/Footer"));
const FunFact = lazy(() => import("sections/index/FunFact"));
const Home = lazy(() => import("sections/index/Home"));
const Project = lazy(() => import("sections/index/Project"));
const Testimonial = lazy(() => import("sections/index/Testimonial"));
const Work = lazy(() => import("sections/index/Work"));

// ... code ommited


<Suspense fallback={null}>
  <Home />
  <About />
  <FunFact />
  <Education />
  <Work />
  <Project />
  <Testimonial />
  <Contact />
  <Footer />
</Suspense>
```